# Javascript Validation Conflict

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a search bar in my header. I did a validation test on it that if it is empty and the user presses the "Search" button then it should display a dialog box saying to "Write the product name". This validation works However on a couple of pages I have a search option that lets the user enter the price range for which he/she wants to see the products. They both are distinct and two different forms but for some odd reason when I put validation on the price range form, the validation skips that and displays the same "Write the product name" dialog box and highlights the search bar red which it shouldn't do at all. What can be the reason for it?

Here's the code for the search bar validation and form

```
<script>
function checkforblank()
{
if(document.getElementById('search').value == "")
{
    alert('Please type a product name first');
    document.getElementById('search').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;       
}
}
</script>

<form action ="http://localhost/MyOnlineStoreOwn/product_search_result.php"        method="post">
     <input type ="text"name="search" id = "search" placeholder="Search for          products..." align="right"  />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form></td>
```

Here's the code for price range search box and form

```
function checkforblank()
{
if(document.getElementById('price1').value == "")
{
    alert('Please enter price first');
    document.getElementById('price1').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;       
}

if(document.getElementById('price2').value == "")
{
    alert('Please enter price first');
    document.getElementById('price2').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;       
}       
}
</script>

<form     action="http://localhost/MyOnlineStoreOwn/product_list_priceSearch.php"  onsubmit="return checkforblank()" method="post">
    $<input name="price1" type="text" id="price1" size=8 /> 
 to <br/>
$<input name="price2" type="text" id="price2" size=8 /> <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="sprice" value="Go" >
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    if(isset($_GET['deleteid']))
    {
      echo 'Do you really want to delete this item with ID of '      .$_GET['deleteid']. '? <a href = "inventory_list.php?  yesdelete='.$_GET['deleteid']. '"> Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">   No</a>';   
      exit(); // doesn't render the whole page, only prompts the question    script.
    }
```

how do I make a dialog box to ask the "Do you really want" part and if the user selects yes it does:    Yes
and he/she selects no then it does this: 
I was having trouble writing the  part inside of an echo statement because of the "" or ''..how do i write the correct syntax for  echo "alert('Are you sure Y/N'); if yes do this and if no do this?

Comment: maybe it's because both functions are called `checkforblank` ?

Comment: can anyone help me out on the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant have two functions on the same name. Might be you are getting the alert because the search script is loaded first.
2. For form validation, you need to write your code is another format. [check this from w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).
3. Try different function names.